# Why did "он" suddenly become so much more common?

Tags: орфография, род, местоимения

[image]

In the case of English, "she" was used much less than "he", and it still hasn't caught up. In Russian, it looks as if the translation of "he" almost didn't exist, until around 1915. What happened?

Comment: Russian orthography reform happened.

Answer (score 28):

Actually, the year is not "around 1915", but the beginning of 1918 when the [orthography reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_Russian_orthography#The_post-revolution_reform) began. Before 1918 "он" was written as "онъ", and naturally before 1918 "он" was not used. Have a look:
[image]

After 1918, **Ъ** at the end of words after "hard" consonants was used mainly by emigrants in their printed publications. All the instances of "он" used before 1918 that Ngram Viewer shows in its graphs are actually mistakes of the Google Books OCR.

Comment: I think graph with all three pronouns is more informative. https://goo.gl/4GJYkA

Comment: Also note that Google Ngram Viewer uses a 3-year smoothing window by default, which partly explains why the OP's graph seems to start climbing up around year 1915 = 1918 - 3. Switching to 1-year smoothing, or no smoothing at all, shows the sharpness of the change much more clearly.

Comment: @Alissa - I updated the answer as you suggested, thank you.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - A good point! I absolutely agree with you.

Comment: Actually, ъ was after all consonants: плащъ, врачъ.

Comment: @user31264 - OK, it was really used after Щ and Ч, but definitely not after all consonants, it was never used after Й.

Comment: Only because Й (*и с краткой*) was not considered a consonant.  Today it is considered as полугласная согласная (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)